# UDF function with values from different worksheet as argument

Tags: excel, vba

I have got an UDF that takes some parameters and some of them are from the current workbook, while some come from another workbook. When in 1st workbook I write `=getCOF(` and select all values/ranges I need from both workbooks the function works well, but if I close the 2nd workbook, all of returns of my function beacome `#ARG`. How can I make my function work even if workbook it's working on is closed?

```
Public Function getCOF(values_from_1_workbook As Date, values_from_2nd_workbook As Range) As Double
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = table_to_search.Rows.Count
    DoStuff...
    getCOF = values_from_2nd_workbook(i)
End Function
```

Comment: You can't pass the values as a `Range`, you'll need to use an array.

Comment: You mean I should convert `values_from_2nd_workbook` from `Range` into `array` or just within arguments declaration declare it as an array `Public Function getCOF(values_from_1_workbook As Date, values_from_2nd_workbook As Varriant) As Double`?

Comment: The UDF needs the data, and closing the second workbook makes the data non existent. Have you tried passing the Range as a linked range? `='PATH\[FILENAME.xlsx]SHEETNAME'!$A$1:$A$10`

Comment: Yes, the argument needs to be declared as an array or variant. You can't convert from a range within the UDF as it will never get that far.

Comment: @RicardoA no, I haven't. I was selecting the range by simply holding left mouse button.

@Rory how can I declare an array within function's arguments? `Public Function getCOF(..., values_from_2nd_workbook() As Single) As Double`?

Comment: Declare the argument as `Variant`, then convert within the UDF if necessary.

Comment: @Rory after declaring the arguments as `Variant` instead of `Range` it is still returning an error after closing the 2nd workbook.
Now i see @RicardoA that indeed I was passing to my function a linked range `PATH\[FILE][SHEET]!CELLS` but even tho after closing the file function stops to work. To mention: my 2nd workbook is on shared disk therefore it may not be accesible all times?

Comment: The problem is most likely within your code (which you haven't posted) then. Also, if the source file is not available, then the function will likely error!

Comment: @TimWilliams It doesn't have to open it as long as the argument is not passed as a range object. Values can be passed from closed workbooks as long as a range is not required (eg SUMPRODUCT works with closed source, COUNTIF doesn't)

Comment: @Rory - huh I guess I never tried that, thanks.

Comment: @Rory pardon the request for enlightenment, but I believe this ties into something Mat's Mug posted about years ago (which I can't seem to find).  Is this due to the `Range` being taken to memory at time of invocation (which may be after the source has closed), whereas the values are already allocated in the memory?  Any clarification would be appreciated... nice to know more of the ins/outs.

Comment: @Cyril I don't claim to know the ins and outs of how Excel passes ranges to functions (whether built-in or custom) but most of the key objects in the Excel OM depend on the source file being open - eg Workbooks/Worksheets/Ranges cannot be used unless the source file is open.